# Implementing horizontal scrolling in a UITable (row by row) for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

As per the question, I'm looking to implement a video selector with different categories.  This would be very similar to the BBC app in approach.  I don't seem to be able to find anything that fits the bill though, has anyone got any good ideas for how I might be able to do this/an API freely available that does it.  See example:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/img/BBC_News_app_portrait_BBC_copyright.PNG

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scrollview instead of tableview for this case.

You can make a custom view for each of the news items and can be added to the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a simple UITableView and, inside each cell, create a UIScrollView :)

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)];
myScrollView.delegate = self;
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000,100);

for(int i = 0; i < [myData count]; i++) {
// Add your content here
}
```

Comment: Ah cool I'll have a go with that, I wasn't sure if the scroll view supported that sort of behaviour (noob alert!)  I'll give that a try.  Many thanks...

Comment: You're welcome; I did the same kind of work, UISCrollView works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this [pageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) sample code. It has horizontal scrolling with pages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **three20** classes.

There are downloadable from here: https://github.com/facebook/three20

In sample code you can find horizontally table scroll.
Easy and beatiful!

A

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial, with example project showing an effective way to implement vertical and horizontal scrolling.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1